# How to decide between EAGER and LAZY loading in Hibernate

Tags: lazy-loading, eager-loading

In hibernate or OpenJPA, if I do `FetchType.EAGER`, I risk loading unnecessary data and hurting performance.
If I do `FetchType.LAZY`loading, I risk running into `N + 1` problem.
Are there any guidelines what fetch mode to use when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the general guidelines suggested by @D.R.:

**Lazy** loading on one hand imply **memory saving**, on the other hand imply **increasing the number of queries to the db**. **Eager** loading is **the opposite**.

You have to choose your poison.

Besides, I think it is worth to mention the possibility to override fetching strategies with [hibernate fetch profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles) (if you plan to use hibernate). When a predefined lazy approach isn't enough flexible, it is a good solution.
Using fetch profiles you tell hibernate to fetch object in a "different way" just for that transaction. Very handy when you have to get object lazily, but sometimes you need a different approach.

If you adopt a second level cache optimization, you should check for compatibility since the current fetch profile implementation supports a JOIN strategy.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use eager fetching in all cases where you immediately afterwards need the data. If you run into the N+1 problem, just re-execute the query with eager fetching.

There are of course much more *opinions* for more specific situations, however, I guess, SO is not the best place to discuss things.